# Should I include the name[s] of copywriting agencies I write for on my CV?

Tags: copywriting

I'm a startup copywriter, and some agencies request a CV on application to join. Should I include the name[s] of some of the agencies I already work with and which send me jobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is maybe a question more apt to Workplace.SE, but here's my two cents:

I woudn't mention the names of the agencies you're already working for. This for a few reasons:

- The other agencies may be not happy with that
- Depending on your country rules and on your contracts, you may disclosing confidential information
- You don't necessarily want people know that you're working for agency X, unless you are sure that agency X fame will reflect positively on your own.

I'd personally go with something along the lines

> I have worked with a number of agencies, including a multinational in
>   fashion exports, a medium sized manufacturing company, a law studio, a
>   small firm ...

This shows that you have past experience and clarifies in which settings that  experience was. You may include also what kind of content you have copyrighted to get your potential employers a good grasp of what you've dealt with.

If asked, provide additional details only if you're certain that the interested agencies are OK with it.